# converting response to array in laravel 8

Tags: arrays, laravel, api

this function in returning the data of the organization and converts it to an array but is facing an issue in converting the collection to an array in laravel 8 for the 'created_schedule' index, every record is also a collection but only haveing issues in schedule because i want to use 1 query and filter record on the basis of published and created schedule

```
public function getOrganizationData(): JsonResponse
    {
        $manager = auth('manager')->user();
        try {
            $data = [];
            $routes = Route::where('o_id', $manager->o_id)
                ->where('status', Route::STATUS_ACTIVE)
                ->select('id', 'name')
                ->get();

            $vehicles = Vehicle::where('o_id', $manager->o_id)
                ->where('status', Vehicle::STATUS_ACTIVE)
                ->select('id', 'number as  name')
                ->get();

            $drivers = Driver::where('o_id', $manager->o_id)
                ->where('status', Driver::STATUS_ACTIVE)
                ->select('id', 'name')
                ->get();

            $schedules = Schedule::with('organizations:id,name')
                ->with('routes:id,name,number,from,to')
                ->with('vehicles:id,number')
                ->with('drivers:id,name')
                ->where('o_id', $manager->o_id)
                ->whereDate('date', date('Y-m-d'))
                ->whereIn('status', [Schedule::STATUS_PUBLISHED, Schedule::STATUS_DRAFT])
                ->select('id', 'o_id', 'route_id', 'v_id', 'd_id', 'date', 'time', 'status', 'created_at')
                ->get();

            $published = $schedules->filter(function ($schedule) {
                return $schedule->status === Schedule::STATUS_PUBLISHED;
            });

            $created = $schedules->filter(function ($schedule) {
                return $schedule->status === Schedule::STATUS_DRAFT;
            });

            $created = $created->toArray();
            $published = $published->toArray();

            $data = [
                'routes' => $routes,
                'vehicles' => $vehicles,
                'drivers' => $drivers,
                'published_schedule' => $published,
                'created_schedule' => $created
            ];
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Data not found ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->respondWithSuccess(
            $data,
            'Organization route, vehicle, driver data, published and created schedule',
            'ORGANIZATION_ROUTE_VEHICLE_DRIVER_DATA_SCHEDULE'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each of the `$created` items is also possibly a collection, try using map on it to convert it to an array individually. Something like:

```php
$created = $created->map(function ($schedule) {
    return $schedule->toArray();
})->toArray();
```

Or you could chain it to your previous method like:

```php
$created = $schedules->filter(function ($schedule) {
    return $schedule->status === Schedule::STATUS_DRAFT;
  })
  ->map(function ($schedule) {
    return $schedule->toArray();
  })
  ->toArray();
```